# Could not connect to iTunes Store issue inapp purchase objective c

Tags: objective-c, testing, in-app-purchase, itunes, storekit

I am working on inApp purchase in objective c. I setup almost everything fine in itunesconnect and write code on my project. Here's my code

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
    switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:[self UnlockPurchase];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:NSLog(@"Transaction Failed");
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            NSLog(@"error: %@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry"
                                                            message:transaction.error.localizedDescription
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
    }
}
```

}

When I press Buy button it ask to sign in with "Use Existing Apple ID" and is working fine if sandbox user id is entered. 
But If I have signed in with free apple ID on my phone settings in both 'iCloud' and 'iTunes & App Store' the above code goes to SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed case. At the same time if I try to buy something on other apps it ask to purchase from App Store with pop up from bottom.
[image: Screenshot of another app]

Please anyone show me the way to ask for purchase as shown on above screenshot even if the user has signed in iTunes & App Store. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't there any mula saag to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about that, it's the behavior with sandbox and apple. In prod, you'll have a popup from the bottom. Thanks to apple

Comment: Hi @ludo, I see you are new to this site. Typically, for answers like this, it is recommended to provide a link to some documentation that backs up your answer, and not merely just saying "it is the default behavior." Thanks for your contribution!